# Remove style of this concrete string?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I extracted the following string from a webpage. It seems to somehow contain font styling, which makes it hard to work with. I would like to convert it to ordinary unstyled characters, using Python.

Here is the string:

Comment: Python strings have no notion of styling.  What does Python show if you print the string?

Comment: It's just a matter of Unicode normalization; compare `[ord(c) for c in "  "]` with `[ord(c) for c in unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "  ")]`.

Comment: The original question indicated that simply pasting the string into `python` would show what he meant; the "styling" is inferred from the Unicode characters present in the string.

Comment: You can subtract the offset of the unicode representation of one of the characters.

Comment: For example, `unicodedata.name("")` will tell you that this is `'MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD SMALL K'`.

Comment: Rollinng back the original question; it could be clearer, but the edit completely eliminated the key to seeing what the string is.

Comment: @chepner I'm not going to argue, but by "the key" do you mean the sentence "copy it and paste it to a py/ipynb"?

Comment: Yes; I was skeptical, too, but when I did that, it indeed displayed (more or less) exactly as shown here (because it's the glyphs selected by your font to display the Unicode characters that are bold, not any additional styling information embedded in the string).

Comment: Short answer: the string does not consist of ASCII characters, but rather Unicode variants that can be *mapped* to ASCII characters via normalization.

Comment: @chepner I tried to convey in my edit that this is literally what the string looks like by including it in code fences.

Comment: I solved using @chepner soluition ! Thank you a lot! `''.join([c for c in unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "  ")])`

Comment: @chepner: They probably want "NFKC", not "NFKD". "NFKD" turns `ñ` into two characters (`n` + combining `~`). And you can do the whole string with one call to `unicodedata.normalize`; you don't need to do it character by character. I would have answered, but the question was closed.

Comment: @rici Thanks. I knew they were different, but couldn't remember *what* the difference was. `NFKD` worked for this one and I left it at that. The character-by-character was just to show  more clearly that the result was different and produced ASCII characters.

Comment: @SrtoPeixet Just use `unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", "  ")`. You get the ASCII string back; I only use the list comprehension to call `ord` on each character to show the difference between the Unicode codeponts and the ASCII code points. No need to make a list of characters to reconcatenate.

Comment: That's it! Thank you a lot!! By the way, do you know why the question is closed and not accepting answers?

Comment: It was closed because three people with close privileges thought the question didn't describe the issue precisely enough. I tried to improve it; perhaps @chepner has a comment about my efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters in that string are special Unicode codepoints used for mathematical typography. Although they shouldn't be used in other contexts, many webpages abuse Unicode for the purpose of creating styled texts; it is most common in places where HTML styling is not allowed (like StackOverflow comments :-)

As indicated in the comments, you can convert these Unicode characters into ordinary unstyled alphabetic characters using the standard `unicodedata` module's [`normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html?highlight=normalize#unicodedata.normalize) method to do "compatibility (`K`) composition (`C`)" normalization.

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", "  ")
```

There are four normalization forms, which combine two axes:

- **composition** or **decomposition**:
  Certain characters (like `ñ` or `Ö`) have their own Unicode codepoints, although Unicode also includes a mechanism --zero-width "combining characters"-- to apply decorations ("accents" or "tildes") to any character. The precomposed characters with their own codes are basically there to support older encodings (like ISO-8859-x) which included these as single characters. Ñ, for example, was hexadecimal `D1` in ISO-8859-1 ("latin-1"), and it was given the Unicode codepoint `U+00D1` to make it easier to convert programs which expected it to be a single character. Latin-1 also includes Õ (as `D5`), but it does not include T̃; in Unicode, we write T̃ as two characters: a capital T followed by a "combining tilde" (U+0054 U+0303). That means we could write Ñ in two ways: as Ñ, the single composed codepoint U+00D1, or as Ñ, the two-code sequence U+004E U+0303. If your display software is well-tuned, those two possibilities should look identical, and according to the Unicode standard they are semantically identical, but since the codes differ, they won't compare the same in a byte-by-byte comparison.

  - **Composition** (C) normalization converts multi-code sequences into their composed single-code versions, where those exist; it would turn U+004E U+0303 into U+00D1.
  - **Decomposition** (D) normalization converts the composed single-code characters into the semantically equivalent sequence using combining characters; it would turn U+00D1 into U+004E U+0303
- **compatibility** (K):
  Some Unicode codepoints exist only to force particular rendering *styles*. That includes the styled math characters you encountered, but it also includes ligatures (such as `ﬃ`), superscript digits (²) or letters (ª) and some characters which have conventional meanings (µ, meaning "one-millionth", which different from the Greek character μ, or the Angstrom sign Å, which is not the same as the Scandinavian character Å). In compatibility normalization, these characters are changed to the base unstyled character; in some cases, this loses important semantic information, but it can be useful.

All normalizations put codes into "canonical" ordering. Characters with more than one combining marks, such as ḉ, can be written with the combining marks in either order. To make it easier to compare strings which contain such characters, Unicode has a designated combining order, and normalization will reorder combining characters so that they can be easily compared. (Note that this needs to be done after composition, since that can change the base character. For example, if the base character is "ç" decomposition normalization will change the base character to "c" and the cedilla will then need to be inserted in the correct place in the sequence of combining marks.